# Laravel 5 generate subdomain aware URL

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, subdomain

I am trying to create an application that will have about 4 sub domains and one main domain i.e. `www` domain. 
Now let's assume i am in `http://subdomain1.example.com` and i want to generate a URL to a product like this `http://subdomain2.example.com/product/id`
`{{ url('product/id') }}` produces

```
http://subdomain1.example.com/product/id
```

I want it to be

```
http://subdomain2.example.com/product/id
```

This is what i have in the routes.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.{domain}.{tld}'], function () {
        // routes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to do this using named routes. something like this -

routes.php -

```php
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain2.example.com'], function () {
        Route::get('product/{id}', ['as' => 'product', function ($id) {
            //probably would want to put this under controller 
        }]);
});
```

and to get the url you would do -
`route('product', ['id' => 1]);`

Comment: The sub domains are dynamic based on the name of the category so i have used the route group as
`Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.{domain}.{tld}'], function () {
        // routes
});`
So i think this will not work

Comment: well you needed to mentioned that earlier ... I guess your only way is to create a custom url builder and build the url's yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Hy, you can use this one:

routes.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{subdomain}.domain.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function(){
        ...
    })->name('somename'); 
});
```

In your view:

```
{{ route('somename', 'subdomain-as-param') }}
```

It will make an url:

```
http://subdomain-as-param.domain.com
```

Comment: What about for URLs that do not have named routes? What about to generate URLs for assets such as CSS, JS, or image assets? This solution does not cover that and is not really acceptable.

Comment: Are you sure? :D Please have a look into the documentation before you put your wrong comment here..